# Selenium: "is not clickable at point" how to wait till all scripts were loaded

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, selenium, webdriver

I have 3 waits:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='pagecontrols']/input[1]")));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='pagecontrols']/input[1]")));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='pagecontrols']/input[1]")));
```

For the same element, but after waits, when I want to click

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='pagecontrols']/input[1]")).click();
```

I have :

> "Element (...) is not clickable at point"

I was trying to wait for JavaScript to loaded completly, by adding this part

```
public void waitForLoad(WebDriver driver) 
{
  ExpectedCondition<Boolean> pageLoadCondition = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() 
  {
    public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) 
    {  
      return ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
    }
  };
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
  wait.until(pageLoadCondition);
}
```

However this is not working (this help in different place, so generally this helping in some cases), maybe I'm doing something wrong?
I think I should wait for jQuery too, but honestly I do know how (I've found some solutions for that, but they didn't worked for me)

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#adduser" data-localize="adduser" value="Add user"> is not clickable at point (1397, 97). Other element would receive the click: <div class="blockUI blockOverlay" style="z-index: 1000; border: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); cursor: wait; position: absolute; opacity: 0.304712;"></div>
  (Session info: chrome=55.0.2883.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 149 milliseconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:43:45 -0700'
System info: host: 'BTIS1000062581', ip: 'x.x.x.x', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_20'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9), userDataDir=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir7068_2467}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=55.0.2883.87, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
Session ID: e9c9bf2150b10d2865e7a117c1c9e739
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:635)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:274)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:84)
    at automationFramework.FirstTestCase.main(FirstTestCase.java:201)
```

**One more thing: When I add
Thread.sleep(500);
before clicking element it is working, but I want to get rid of those sleeps**

Comment: Paste entire exception you get here.

Comment: That can happen if the element you want to click is obstructed by another element. Could you post a sample of the web page you're testing?

Comment: This page is accessable only in my network

Comment: https://images84.fotosik.pl/311/766aa577c599eb26.png

Answer (score 1):

The only real and effective way to avoid this "smoke" UI blocker is using Thread.sleep(); 3000 millis and voila!

Answer (score 0):

You should wait until element that intercepts click disappeared:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath('//div[@class="blockUI blockOverlay"]')));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Add user']")).click();
```

Comment: It's working - but it is taking a lot of time.
Honestly I don't know What is happening, it should check this element "//div[@class='blockUI blockOverlay']"
every 500ms, max 10 times, but for me it takes longer than 5s

Comment: @Krzysztof then change new WebDriverWait(driver, 10) to new WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

Comment: still the same - I was trying to change it, without results

`System.out.println("before waiting "+System.currentTimeMillis());`

`new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='blockUI blockOverlay']")));`
       
`System.out.println("after waiting "+System.currentTimeMillis());`

before waiting 1485261322976
after waiting 1485261335940

so 13s

Answer (score 0):

I believe that adding a wait for page load should work fine here:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: I'm using this, but without results

Answer (score 0):

you should expect the block-ui to disappear before the click action or any other action.
something for example:

```
public void aguardaBlockUi(){
        WebElement elementBlock = (findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='blockUI blockOverlay']")));

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait( driver, 180 );
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(elementBlock ));   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I subclassed webdriver to intercept .find_element_by_*() and delay until all blockUI divs were gone.  This made my main code cleaner.

```py
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


class MyChrome(Chrome):

    def find_element(self, by=By.ID, value=None):
        # Wait until jQuery BlockUI Plugin removes of all elements
        # NOTE: driver=super() to avoid RecursionError
        WebDriverWait(super(), 10).until_not(EC.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.blockUI'),
        ))

        return super().find_element(by=by, value=value)
```